# Performance Testing of Microsoft service Bus

Tags: jmeter

I need to do performance testing of microsoft service bus (which is accessed by nane space) I am using jmeter for performance testing, I understand that Jmeter can be configured to put in messages using Jmeter, Is it possible to do same for Microsoft service bus.
Is there any other tool which can support us.

Comment: I am new to queues, does anyone load tested Micrsoft service bus running on Microsoft server to test using JMeter

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter for Microsoft Service Bus testing with [Apache QPid JMS Client](https://qpid.apache.org/download.html) libraries.

References:

- [Using Service Bus for Windows Server from Java with AMQP 1.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn574799.aspx)
- [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter)

Comment: I was able to install the certificate using key tool. But not sure how do i use the code and using JMS test plans. As JMS test plan using factory JNDI.